# Kubernetes Pod DNS Resolution

Tags: internal-dns, kubernetes

Currently able to resolve all services to IP addresses and telnet and ping them. Unable to resolve pods to IP addresses. Though can lookup pod IP addresses with kubectl and telnet and ping them. 
How do I need DNS configured to resolve pods in Kubernetes 1.9.6, dns-controller:1.9.1.

Comment: the_frank where do you the read that kubernetes creates dns records for pods?

Comment: here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

Comment: by default into the /etc/resolver.conf of the pod, I only see this entries default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local , I the docs suggest need to be enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@mk_sta 's answer a bit easier to work with you can run this one liner to test your DNS:

`kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm --attach --command -- sh -c "cat /etc/resolv.conf; nslookup $POD.$NAMESPACE.pod.cluster.local"`

Example output:

```
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

Server:         100.64.0.10
Address:        100.64.0.10:53


*** Can't find $POD.$NAMESPACE.pod.cluster.local: No answer

deployment.apps "busybox" deleted
```

Bonus is that it deletes the deployment/pods after running.

---

For me the problem was that my pods are in a statefulset and therefore Pod DNS resolution is a bit different. You have to use (for example):

`web-{0..N-1}.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local`

`pod-N.$GOVERNING_STATEFULSET.$NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

That's one thing that can go wrong. You may want to provide more info about your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create test Pod with `busybox` in order to check DNS resolving function and debug the issue:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Check `/etc/resolv.conf` file on the `busybox` Pod:

```
kubectl exec busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

The content should be like this:

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local .....
nameserver 10.0.0.10
options ndots:5
```

Make a lookup request to the target Pod in your cluster:

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup XXX-XX-XX-XX.default.pod.cluster.local
```

In case you have not been resolved Pods DNS name, you can check DNS components logs with`kubectl logs` command:

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c healthz
```

Comment: The bottom 3 commands exit with an error: kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
error: only one of -c or an inline [CONTAINER] arg is allowed
See 'kubectl logs -h' for help and examples.

Comment: Have you used kube-dns as DNS resolving service in your cluster?

Comment: kube-dns is the current DNS resolver in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have seen to resolve this is by creating a Jump Pod.

Step 1. Create the pod with a spec file.

```
cat << ENDL >> jumpod.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jumpod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
ENDL
```

Step 2. Ether apply or create the pod into the cluster and on to a node. Note that it will be located at the default namespace.

```
kubectl apply -f jumpod.yml
```

Now you can use this pod to either get the DNS of a Pod or Service.

For Example:

**Pod nslookup**
Step 3. Get the ip address of the pod you are looking for.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Step 4. Use the Jump Pod to do an nslookup

```
kubectl exec -it jumpod ping 10.244.0.149
```

**Service nslookup**
Step 5. Lookup the services ip address that you may want to use.

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
```

Step 6. Now use the jump pod to do an nslookup on the service ip address

```
kubectl exec -it jumpod nslookup 10.245.150.103
```

Below is an example on how the main cluster using nslookup will not work and how the busybox (aka jump pod) will work.

```
$ kubectl exec -it jumpod nslookup 10.245.150.103
Server:    10.245.0.10
Address 1: 10.245.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Name:      10.245.150.103
Address 1: 10.245.150.103 hello.develop.svc.cluster.local
$ nslookup 10.245.150.103
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
** server can't find 103.150.245.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Hope this helps!

P.S 
If by chance you need to export the DNS file you created within the pod you can use this.

```
kubectl cp default/POD_NAME:bin/FILE_NAME /Users/username/FILE_NAME
```

or just use > to export it to a file.